# Using predict on a linear regression model in Tensor flow Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I am new to tensor-flow, and am following its suggested beginners tutorial.  Here is a snippet of my code relating to the linear regressor.

```
#Configure the linear regressor model
linear_regressor = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
    feature_columns = feature_columns,
    optimizer = my_optimizer,
    model_dir = "/Users/nickglidden/Desktop/pythonwork/aidentensor
```

aidentensor is the folder that containes all the files needed for this tutorial(this python file, and a CSV file) Intuitively, thats where I should store my trained model right?

However, when I execute my code..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/nickglidden/Desktop/pythonwork/aidentensor/first.py", line 85, in <module>
predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in predictions])
File "/Users/nickglidden/Desktop/pythonwork/aidentensor/first.py", line 85, in <listcomp>
predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in predictions])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 488, in predict
self._model_dir))
ValueError: Could not find trained model in model_dir: /Users/nickglidden/Desktop/pythonwork/aidentensor.
```

I see the error relates to the predictions statements, here they are:

```
predictions = linear_regressor.predict(input_fn=prediction_input_fn)

predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in predictions])
```

The original tutorial does not even include the model_dir="" in the linear regression code, I stumbled upon someone else who had this problem, and someone suggested adding the model_dir was the stated solution. Same error is thrown wether I include it or not. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi NSGlidden, the error `ValueError: Could not find trained model in model_dir: /Users/nickglidden/Desktop/pythonwork/aidentensor.` clearly states that it is not able to locate the model file in given directory. Could you please make sure the model file exist at a defined location or give the complete path like **r'C:\Users\...'**

Comment: Mr. Patel, thank you for your quick response. "aidentensor" is a folder, so in the folder I added a file called "trained_model.py" and then in my code, appended my path to /aidentensor/trained_model.py" and it still couldn't find it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, can you upload your project files and Dataset files as Github repository so that I can have a look at it?